# How to correctly animate UILabel inside cells in a UICollectionView?

Tags: swift, ios8, uicollectionviewcell, uiviewanimation

Hey guys I have this piece of code that fade out and in the UILabel that's inside a cell in a UICollectioView. The labels are displayed correctly when the App is running, the problem is: the animation does not happen.

I have the same code but using UITableView and it works fine, but not with UICollectionView. Here's the code:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell : Cells = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cells

    cell.prodImg.image = UIImage(named: prodImgs[indexPath.row])
    cell.prodName.text = prodNomes[indexPath.row]
    cell.prodName.alpha = 1.0
    cell.prodName.hidden = false

    cellsArray = [collectionView.visibleCells()]
            return cell
}


override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    for cell in cellsArray {
        println(cell)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            cell.prodName?.alpha = 0.0
            return
        })
    }
}


override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    for cell in cellsArray {
        println(cell)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            cell.prodName?.alpha = 1.0
            return
        })
    }

}
```

So anyone have an idea to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure both of the `scrollViewDid` functions are being executed (is the `println(cell)` happening for both of them)?

Comment: Yes oltman, both println are working too. This is strange, I am not sure if the code is not working because I am using Xcode 6.1 newest Beta or the problem is really with the code itself.

Comment: I did another test and it seems that the problem is with the for loop. I commented out the animation code and added cell.prodName?.hidden = true so that the label would just be hidden.  Nothing happened again. Strange, because the println prints the cells while I am scrolling, but still nothing happens to the labels. Another note, competing this code with the one I did for UITableViews it has one difference: instead of looping in cellsArray, I looped in tableView.visibleCells() and this worked, but using collectionView.visibleCells() throws me an error. That's why I use cellsArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I managed to get it working. Here is how I got it working:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
for cell in self.collectionView?.visibleCells() as [Cells] {
    println(cell)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        cell.prodName?.alpha = 0.0
        return
    })
}
}


override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
for cell in self.collectionView?.visibleCells() as [Cells] {
    println(cell)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        cell.prodName?.alpha = 1.0
        return
    })
}

}
```